# How to create function to remove rows with certain strings in data frame list?

Tags: r

I have a data set similarly to the one below, I am attempting to remove all rows that have `Totals` or empty strings in the first column `y1` across the data list.

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c("", 2, 3),
                 y2 = c(4, 5, 6))
d2 <- data.frame(y1 = c("Total", 2, 1),
                 y2 = c(6, 5, 4))
d3 <- data.frame(y1 = c(1, 2, 3),
                 y2 = c(4, 5, 6))
d4 <- data.frame(y1 = c("", 2, 1),
                 y2 = c(6, 5, 4))
d5 <- data.frame(y1 = c(1, "Total", 3),
                 y2 = c(4, 5, 6))
my.list <- list(d1, d2,d3,d4,d5)
```

I have tried a using `lapply` with `mutate` functions but I have not been able to find any fix across to the data frame list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `subset` by looping over the `list` with `lapply`

```
my.list2 <- lapply(my.list, subset, subset = y1 != 'Total' & y1 != "")
```

Or with `%in%`

```
my.list2 <- lapply(my.list, subset, subset = !y1 %in% c("Total", ""))
```